# Subtract Lowpass from Wire to Get Allpass

Tags: filter-design, finite-impulse-response, lowpass-filter, dsp-puzzle

One technique to make a high pass filter is to subtract a lowpass filter from a wire (meaning subtract the output of the filter from the input as I have demonstrated in [this post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/79441/21048)).

What lowpass can you subtract from a wire that will result in an all-pass? Specifically pass all frequencies with unity gain and modify the phase only, such that the group delay is 1 sample?

This is a “DSP Puzzle”, please preface your answer with spoiler notation by typing ythe following two characters first ">!"

Comment: can you clarify the group delay requirement please? On first blush the allpass vs group delay of one sample seems in conflict. A constant delay of one sample sure is an allpass but in general a non-trivial allpass has a frequency dependent group delay

Comment: @Hilmar To confirm, the resulting all pass will have a constant group delay over all frequencies (linear phase). Basically a lossless cable with delay (which is indeed an all-pass). I'm happy with referring to it as a "trivial allpass".

Comment: Cool. Well, this disqualifies all my favorites "add to allpass" pairs, but that's probably not what you wanted anyway :-)

Comment: @hilmar Well actually that would be quite interesting to see and know about (but doesn’t answer this). Consider posting it as a short blog post at dsprelated.com!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Not only a lowpass filter but also a highpass filter is possible: $$\delta[n]-h[n]=\pm\delta[n-1]$$ which implies $$h[n]=\delta[n]\pm\delta[n-1]\tag{1}$$ where the positive sign in $(1)$ results in a simple first order FIR lowpass filter, and the negative sign corresponds to a highpass filter. Note that both filters, when subtracted from a wire, result in an allpass filter with a group delay of one sample. Of course, the phase responses are different.

Answer (score 3):

> Let APF $A(z)$ be $$ A(z) = \frac{z^{-N} + a_1z^{1-N} + ... + a_{N-1}z^{-1} + a_N}{1 + a_1z^{-1} + ... + a_{N-1}z^{1-N} + a_Nz^{-N}} $$ Then define your complementary filter as $$\begin{align} H(z) &= 1 - A(z) \\ \\ &= 1 - \frac{z^{-N} + a_1z^{1-N} + ... + a_{N-1}z^{-1} + a_N}{1 + a_1z^{-1} + ... + a_{N-1}z^{1-N} + a_Nz^{-N}} \\\\&=  \frac{1 + a_1z^{-1} + ... + a_{N-1}z^{1-N} + a_Nz^{-N}}{1 + a_1z^{-1} + ... + a_{N-1}z^{1-N} + a_Nz^{-N}} - \frac{z^{-N} + a_1z^{1-N} + ... + a_{N-1}z^{-1} + a_N}{1 + a_1z^{-1} + ... + a_{N-1}z^{1-N} + a_Nz^{-N}} \\ \\&=  \frac{1-a_N + (a_1-a_{N-1})z^{-1} + ... + (a_{N-1}-a_1)z^{1-N} + (a_N-1)z^{-N}}{1 + a_1z^{-1} + ... + a_{N-1}z^{1-N} + a_Nz^{-N}}   \\\end{align}$$

Comment: ... which shows that a filter that can be represented as the difference of two allpass filters has an anti-symmetric numerator polynomial, i.e., its zeros satisfy the same conditions as the zeros of a linear phase FIR filter (they are either on the unit circle, or they occur in pairs mirrored at the unit circle).

Comment: I tried to format the spoiler but gave up.  So what is the conclusion shown (besides interesting observation by Matt)? Or is this still in process? (I didn’t downvote)

Comment: It's not in process.  It's a general answer to the general question expressed in the title.  I realize that ***I*** changed the title to mean what you meant in asking the question.  I also realize that the question was more specific than what was indicated in the title.  I also saw Matt's answer before I wrote this.  I just wanted to answer the question directly as stated in the title.

Answer (score 1):

> Let's consider $H[k]$ is the frequency response(DFT) of the low pass filter that is of interest - satisfies the conditions mentioned in the problem statement.

> Let $x[n]$ represent the original signal and $x_{f}[n]$ be the output signal obtained by passing the signal $x[n]$ through the filter $H[k]$.Let $X[k]$ represent the N-point DFT of $x[n]$, then $$x[n] = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}X[k]. e^\frac{j2\pi nk}{N}$$ The filtered signal can be expressed as$$x_f[n]= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}H[k]X[k]. e^\frac{j2\pi nk}{N} $$ From the problem statement the following relation can be established. Let $y[n]$ represent the signal obtained by subtracting the filtered signal $x_f[n]$ from wire. Then,$$y[n] = x[n] - x_{f}[n] = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}(1-H[k]).X[k]. e^\frac{j2\pi nk}{N}$$ The resulting signal has a constant group delay equal to $1$ and the gain of all frequencies is unity. Hence $$|1-H[k]| = 1$$ and $$\angle{(1-H[k])} = -\frac{2\pi}{N}k $$

> Two trivial solutions for $H[k]$ satisfying the above conditions are as given below:$$H[k]= 1 + e^\frac{-j2\pi k}{N} \; and \; H[k] = 1 - e^\frac{-j2\pi k}{N}$$Applying inverse Fourier transforms to the trivial solutions gives the filter response as below$$h[n] = \delta[n] + \delta[n - 1] \; and\; h[n] = \delta[n] - \delta[n - 1] $$The result is same as what Matt already has posted but the derivation is from frequency domain approach.

Comment: Nice SakSath - This is indeed the answer from a totally different angle (no pun intended) than I had considered.  The result is a two-point DFT.

Comment: Thanks Dan Boschen!